# Spring Data JPA save() return entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring boot data jpa as below

```
 @Entity
  @Table(name = "invoice")
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @ToString
  public class Invoice {


   @Id
    @Column(name = "inv_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger invId;

    @Column(name = "external_id")
    private String externalInvoiceId;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private double amount;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonIgnoreProperties
    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    @Transient
    private String invoiceStatus;


    public String getInvoiceStatus() {
        switch (this.status){
            case 1:
                return "INITIATED";
            case 2:
                return "CANCELLED";
            case 3:
                return "SUCCESS";
            case 4:
                return "FAILURE";
            default:
                return "IN PROGRESS";

        }

    }

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;


    @PostPersist
    public void updateExternalID() {
        this.externalInvoiceId="G".concat(String.valueOf(this.invId.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(1000))))
                                  .concat(String.valueOf(Instant.now().getEpochSecond()));

    }
}
```

Am accesing this entiry via repository as below

```
public interface InvoicesRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, BigInteger> {
}
```

At my `@Service` am performing the below operation

```
@Autowired
    private InvoicesRepository myInvoicesRepository;

    Invoice transactionInvoice = new Invoice();
    transactionInvoice.setAmount(200.0);
    transactionInvoice.setStatus(1);
    Invoice savedInvoice = myInvoicesRepository.save(transactionInvoice);
```

Am using `savedInvoice` and trying to update the status. Either it is not updating the status properly nor I could not find the record in database too.

There are no rollback present

Below are the logs I could see insert statements are present

```
[XNIO-1 task-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement -
    /* insert com.min.app.model.Invoice
        */ insert
        into
            invoice
            (amount, created_at, external_inv_id, status, updated_at)
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate:
    /* insert com.min.app.model.Invoice
        */  insert
        into
            invoice
            (amount, created_at, external_inv_id, status, updated_at)
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

After the status updates I tried printing the `savedInvoice` could see the below in logs

```
Invoice(invId=58, externalInvoiceId=G580001575271905, amount=185.0 status=4, invoiceStatus=FAILURE, createdAt=Mon Dec 02 13:01:45 IST 2019, updatedAt=Mon Dec 02 13:01:45 IST 2019)
```

The above record I could not see in the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're probebly creating and modifying the invoice outside of any transaction.

Comment: @JBNizet The save method of the JpaRepository is transactional

Comment: What database are you using? Set the hibernate logger and check if there is an insert statement

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sure, so if the service which saves then updates the created entity is not transactional, a transaction is opened by the repository save() method, and commits as soon as save() returns, and the service thus modifies a detached entity.

Comment: @JBNizet The asker says: "I could not find the record in database"

Comment: @balaji-srinivasan can you share the code code used to update the status? Note that you need to save it in DB with InvoicesRepository after updating the status.

Comment: Am using MySQL. Am just calling repository.save again with the savedInvoice. I could see the first set of inserts in logs I have it my question. Second time when I call save I could not see anything in logs.

Comment: JPA should set "invId" on the transactionInvoice based on MySQL's IDENTITY. Can you confirm that the returned "savedInvoice" with "invId = 58" has the same "invId" as the transactionInvoice ?

Comment: Yes both has same invid. Everything from logs have same data. I am not able to even see the original invoice that got saved with different state in db.

Comment: can you please share whats config you using for db

Comment: I have voted to close as it is unclear what you are doing here: your code does not reflect what your comments say? *I am not able to even see the original invoice that got saved with different state* What does this mean?? *just calling repository.save again with the savedInvoice* What does this mean?? Are you aware that `transactionInvoice` and `savedInvoice` are the same instance i.e. in the case of calling `save` with a newly created entity the entity you passed and what is returned are the same.

Comment: My initial invoice status is 1. On calling save I stored the result in savedInvoice. Now if I look in db I should have the record or not ? It is not present in db. Whereas in logs I could see the insert statements. Irrespective of that I tried to update the status using savedInvoice and called repository.save with savedInvoice. There is no effect there is still no record in db. But from log when printed the savedInvoice I could see the attributes getting updated successfully. I have mentioned the same in logs.

Comment: How exactly are you invoking these save operations? What is calling your service method?

Comment: Its via a controller only via a endpoint.

Comment: can try `saveAndFlush` instead of `save` method ?

Comment: This seems working. I could see from documentation that it flushes the changes immediately but how is too different from `.save`? Not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to perform transactions in a function call as follows and put your @Autowired repository in Global level ass follows.

```
class whatever{
@Autowired
    private InvoicesRepository myInvoicesRepository;

//call this function
void doSomething(){
    Invoice transactionInvoice = new Invoice();
    transactionInvoice.setAmount(200.0);
    transactionInvoice.setStatus(1);
    Invoice savedInvoice = myInvoicesRepository.save(transactionInvoice);
}
}
```

Comment: Even though I haven't provided the complete class of Service that I mentioned this is how it is actually in the application.